# Splitting text of a single row into multiple rows of the same column in a CSV file using Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

The dictionary has the following key-value pairs:

```
    {
    'Target_Tab': 'employees',
    ' Target_Col': 'empp_id  last_name  first_name',
    'Source_Col': 'emp_id    l_name    f_name',
    'Source_Tab': 'employee'
    }
```

I'm writing this dictionary into a CSV file and so far I've got this:

```
Source_Tab   Source_Col                   Target_Tab    Target_Col
employee     emp_id last_name first_name   employees    empp_id l_name f_name
```

I want to write the Source _col and Target_col values in different rows. Se below is what I need:

```
Source_Tab  Source_Col   Target_Tab  Target_Col
employee    emp_id       employees   empp_id
            last_name                l_name
            first_name               f_name
```

My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
d = [sdict]
d2 = []
col = ["Source_Table","Source_Columns","Target_Table","Target_Columns"]
for i in d:
    temp = {}
    for c in col:
        if c in i:
            temp[c] = i[c]
        else:
            temp[c] = ''
    d2.append(temp)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2, columns=col)
df2.to_csv('test21.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension with `split` for list of `Series` and join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), last replace missing values by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and change order of columns by list `col`:

```
d =  {
    'Target_Tab': 'employees',
    'Target_Col': 'empp_id  last_name  first_name',
    'Source_Col': 'emp_id    l_name    f_name',
    'Source_Tab': 'employee'
    }

col = ["Source_Tab","Source_Col","Target_Tab","Target_Col"]
df = pd.concat([pd.Series(v.split(), name=k) for k, v in d.items()], axis=1).fillna('')[col]
print (df)
  Source_Tab Source_Col Target_Tab  Target_Col
0   employee     emp_id  employees     empp_id
1                l_name              last_name
2                f_name             first_name
```

Another solution:

```
col = ["Source_Tab","Source_Col","Target_Tab","Target_Col"]
df = pd.Series(d).str.split(expand=True).fillna('').reindex(col).T
print (df)
  Source_Tab Source_Col Target_Tab  Target_Col
0   employee     emp_id  employees     empp_id
1                l_name              last_name
2                f_name             first_name
```

EDIT:

If need filter keys in source dictionary:

```
d =  {
    'Target_Tab': 'employees',
    'Target_Col': 'empp_id  last_name  first_name',
    'Source_Col': 'emp_id    l_name    f_name',
    'Source_Tab': 'employee'
    }

L = ['Source_Tab','Source_Col']
df = (pd.concat([pd.Series(v.split(), name=k) for k, v in d.items() if k in L], axis=1)
        .fillna(''))
print (df)
  Source_Col Source_Tab
0     emp_id   employee
1     l_name           
2     f_name
```

Comment: Instead of writing all the dictionary contents to d, how do I just pass the dictionary? sdict is my dictionary if I write `d=[sdict]` I'm getting error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'`

Comment: @shaikhafizunnisa - added new solution

Comment: My bad! I was converting the dictionary to a list, got rid of the error. What id .T doing in your new solution?

Comment: Also is there a way where I can specify on which key-value pair this splitting operation is to be performed? Suppose I don't want it to be done on Target_col just on Source_col. Is it possible?

Comment: @shaikhafizunnisa - here `T` means transpose - [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html). for second comment need filter after creating `DataFrame` or before?

Comment: @shaikhafizunnisa - here the best is filter in list comprehension, edited answer.

Comment: The edit raises error: `ValueError: No objects to concatenate` when I do `d= sdict`. I get this dictionary from a piece of a code thus I can't write the key-value pairs into d .